# Chart.js bar color based on labels values

Tags: chart.js

The code I need is here: 
[chart.js bar chart color change based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633618/chart-js-bar-chart-color-change-based-on-valuehttp://)

Dola changes the color of the bars based on the values of the datasets using `myObjBar.datasets[0].bars`

I want to do the same thing but with the labels values (good, average, bad) e.g.

```
var barChartData = {
    labels: ["good", "average", "bad"],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [1, 3, 10]
        }
    ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("mycanvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myObjBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
          responsive : true
});

var bars = myObjBar.labels[0]; //I need this line
 for(i=0;i<bars.length;i++){
    var color="green";
    if(bars[i].value=="bad"){
       color="red";
       }
       else if(bars[i].value=="average"){
        color="orange"
       }
       else{
        color="green"
       }
       bars[i].fillColor = color;
    }
myObjBar.update();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `bars[i].value` property, you can use `bars[i].label` which gives you the label of the xAxe.

So in your loop, change to this :

```
for(i=0;i<bars.length;i++){
    var color="green";

    if(bars[i].label == "bad"){
        color="red";
    }
    else if(bars[i].label == "average"){
        color="orange"
    }
    else{
        color="green"
    }
    bars[i].fillColor = color;
}
```

You can find the full code in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Loo5d9w5/) and here is its result :

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.