# .datasets is undefined when trying to access bars from chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to recreate this example:

[chart.js bar chart color change based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633618/chart-js-bar-chart-color-change-based-on-value)

With the following code

```
  <script src="/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"></script>
   <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
   <script>
       var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
       window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
           type: 'bar',
           data: {
               labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
               datasets: [{
                   label: '# of Votes',
                   data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 3, 3],
                   fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                   strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                   highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                   highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                   borderWidth: 1
               }]
           },
       });
       var bars = myChart.datasets[0].bars;
       for (i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
           var color = "green";
           //You can check for bars[i].value and put your conditions here
           if (bars[i].value < 3) {
               color = "red";
           } else if (bars[i].value < 5) {
               color = "orange"

           } else if (bars[i].value < 8) {
               color = "yellow"
           } else {
               color = "green"
           }
           bars[i].fillColor = color;
       }
       myChart.update();

   </script>
```

but I get in console the TypeError:

> myChart.datasets is undefined on the line  var bars = myChart.datasets[0].bars;

Do you have an idea what I'm overlooking?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete example you want.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
  
 //Creating a barchart with default values
 var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
 "type": "bar",
 "data": {
  "labels": ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  "datasets": [{
   "label": "My First Dataset",
   "data": [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
   "fill": false,
   "backgroundColor": ["#fb4d4d", "#fb9d4d", "#f8fb4d", "#98fb4d", "#4effee", "#4cb9f8", "#574cf8"],
   "borderColor": ["#fb4d4d", "#fb9d4d", "#f8fb4d", "#98fb4d", "#4effee", "#4cb9f8", "#574cf8"],
   "borderWidth": 1
  }]
 },
 "options": {
  "scales": {
   "yAxes": [{
    "ticks": {
     "beginAtZero": true
    }
   }]
  }
 }
 });
  
   //Getting the bar-chart existing values   
   var bars = myChart.config.data.datasets[0];
   var data = bars.data;
   
   //Updating the existing value (object which holds value) 
   for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var bgcolor = "";
  var brcolor = "";
    
    if (data[i] < 30) {
   bgcolor = "red";
   brcolor = "red";
    } else if (data[i] < 50) {
   bgcolor = "orange";
   brcolor = "orange";
    } else if (data[i] < 80) {
   bgcolor = "yellow";
   brcolor = "yellow";
    } else {
   bgcolor = "green";
   brcolor = "green";
    }
    
    bars.backgroundColor[i] = bgcolor;
    bars.borderColor[i] = brcolor;
   }
   
   //Triggering the chart update in 3 seconds.
   setTimeout(function(){
 myChart.update();
   }, 3000);
   
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

your dataset was empty, was not being done as the example quoted

The correct way to do as the example you mentioned is:

```
var barChartData = {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: '# of Votes',
                   data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 3, 3],
                   fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                   strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                   highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                   highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                   borderWidth: 1
        }
    ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
       window.myObjBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
          responsive : true
    });
       var bars = myObjBar.datasets[0].bars;
    for(i=0;i<bars.length;i++){
       var color="green";
       //You can check for bars[i].value and put your conditions here
       if(bars[i].value<3){
        color="red";
       }
       else if(bars[i].value<5){
        color="orange"

       }
       else if(bars[i].value<8){
        color="yellow"
       }
       else{
        color="green"
       }

       bars[i].fillColor = color;

    }
    myObjBar.update(); //update the cahrt
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/edicarlos10/w4bqzorf/10/) is an example working :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! The example code didn't show anything in my browser, so I combined it with the example from the Chart.js site https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/ and it showed the bars but did not color them (not getting to the lines of code because of the type error).

I can see your addition and the other example from Stackoverflow in JSFiddle, but when tyring it by myself on my computer my browser is showing a blank page.

Comment: The problem is the library version. In my example and the stack example we use the library: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js Version 1.0.2.

Comment: I see, this has been the issue - thank you for the reply!