# Chart js pie chart, darker shade for higher value and lighter shade for lower value. I'm displaying values monthly

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a Pie chart on my dashboard and I'm using chart.js. I have to display monthly amount belong to a category in this pie chart. I will use single color like "Yellow" for this chart and I want the darker shade for the month where the value is higher and lighter shade of yellow where the value is lower.
Is this possible to achive? I tried with the below js code with no success.

Thanks in advance.

```
var amount = {
            CATEGORY : [],
            
        };
        
        var len = data.length;
        //var CATEGORY=[1,1,1];

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (data[i].for_month == "JANUARY") {
                amount.CATEGORY.push(data[i].amount);
            }
            if (data[i].for_month == "FEBURARY") {
                amount.CATEGORY.push(data[i].amount);
            }
            if (data[i].for_month == "MARCH") {
                amount.CATEGORY.push(data[i].amount);
            }
            if (data[i].for_month == "APRIL") {
                amount.CATEGORY.push(data[i].amount);
            }
            if (data[i].for_month == "MAY") {
                amount.CATEGORY.push(data[i].amount);
            }
            if (data[i].for_month == "JUNE") {
                amount.CATEGORY.push(data[i].amount);
            }
            if (data[i].for_month == "JULY") {
                amount.CATEGORY.push(data[i].amount);
            }
            if (data[i].for_month == "AUGUST") {
                amount.CATEGORY.push(data[i].amount);
            }
            if (data[i].for_month == "SEPTEMBER") {
                amount.CATEGORY.push(data[i].amount);
            }
            if (data[i].for_month == "OCTOBER") {
                amount.CATEGORY.push(data[i].amount);
            }
            if (data[i].for_month == "NOVEMBER") {
                amount.CATEGORY.push(data[i].amount);
            }
            else if (data[i].for_month == "DECEMBER") {
                amount.CATEGORY.push(data[i].amount);
            }
            
        }
        var backgroundColors = amount.map(v => sortedData.indexOf(v) >= amount.length - 3 ? 'red' : 'green');
        var data1 = {
            labels : ["CATEGORY"],
            datasets : [
                {
                    label : "Categories",
                    data : [amount.CATEGORY[4], amount.CATEGORY[3], amount.CATEGORY[7], amount.CATEGORY[0], amount.CATEGORY[8], amount.CATEGORY[6], amount.CATEGORY[5], amount.CATEGORY[1], amount.CATEGORY[11], amount.CATEGORY[10], amount.CATEGORY[9], amount.CATEGORY[2]],
                    
                    backgroundColor : backgroundColors,
```

Comment: [maybe this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633618/chart-js-bar-chart-color-change-based-on-value)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dolmushcu, but my values are dynamic I cannot put values like this. I think I would require proper code to achieve this, don't know I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function adjust(color, amount) {
      return '#' + color.replace(/^#/, '').replace(/../g, color => ('0' + Math.min(255, Math.max(0, parseInt(color, 16) + amount)).toString(16)).substr(-2));
    }
```

[Check out here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57401891/13891083)

```js
function adjust(color, amount) {
  return '#' + color.replace(/^#/, '').replace(/../g, color => ('0' + Math.min(255, Math.max(0, parseInt(color, 16) + amount)).toString(16)).substr(-2));
}


var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3', 'value 4'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      backgroundColor: [],
      data: [33, 57, 65, 42]
    }],
  }
});

let dataset = myChart.data.datasets[0];

let data = dataset.data;
let data_ord = [...data].sort();

let plus = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < data_ord.length; i++) {
  let value = data_ord[i];
  dataset.backgroundColor[data.indexOf(value)] = adjust('#fdd500', plus);
  plus -= 30
}
myChart.update();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-d9xgZrVZpmmQlfonhQUvTR7lMPtO7NkZMkA0ABN3PHCbKA5nqylQ/yWlFAyY6hYgdF1Qh6nYiuADWwKB4C2WSw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="150"></canvas>
```